# Shooting Lomography Metropolis as a redscale film?

Tags: film, 35mm, lomo

Has anyone tried shooting [Lomography Metropolis](https://shop.lomography.com/en/lomochrome-metropolis-film-35mm-5pack) as a [redscale](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redscale) film. That is, loaded with the film back to front, so the light hits the red sensitive layer first and then filtered out for the yellow and cyan sensitive layers (or whatever they are in lomo metropolis!).

I found this [article](https://www.lomography.com/magazine/309515-creative-ways-to-shoot-the-lomography-lomochrome-purple-film) where someone tried it with Lomography Purple.

I was wondering if anyone has tried this, before I make my attempt.

Comment: It's been awhile since I checked SE. Did you ever conduct this experiment?

Comment: @OnBreak. I bought a roll, and then promptly lost it haha. I need to tidy up my cupboard hopefully I will find it in there and I'll go out and give it a go. I'll let ya'll know how it turns out.